# Android : Paste on a Text Field outside of our application

Tags: java, android, keyboard, clipboard, paste

I would like to create a button which can paste a text in any text field of any application like on the Google search bar. (this button is simply an overlay and I already have it)

Supposing that I already have something in the clipboard, how can the button perform a paste on any text field?

Language: Java

I have tried to simulate the keyboard but none of the code that I wrote works.

Thanks all!

Comment: That is generally not possible, for security reasons. You are welcome to explore options using an accessibility service, but you should also discuss your plans with your attorney.